Distinguishable objects into distinguishable boxes.
So here is the problem. We have $500$ fans of which $200$ Americans,$150$ Polish, $100$ Italians and $50$ French. They are about to travel to Paris for the start of the Olympic games with 5 different flights. Each flight has $150$ seats.
In how many different ways can the fans fly so that if they are distinguished based on their identity, all Polish must travel on the same flight and all Italians must travel on the same flight?
Firstly, I tried doing this :
Numway $= 5 \cdot 4(3^{250}- \binom{3}{1}3^{99}) $
Where $5$ is the number of ways the first flight can take the Polish or the Italians, $4$ is the remaining ( from the Polish or the Italians ) and $3^{250}$ are the number of ways the $250$ different remaing fans can choose one of the flights without restrictions and $\binom{3}{1}3^{99}$ is the number of ways we can choose one of the $3$ flights in which we can have more than $150$ passengers.
Is this the correct approach or I am missing something?

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

do you know generating functions ?

No they have not taught us about generating functions.

Not making any assumption other than what is written in the question, viz. (i) distinguishable objects and boxes (ii) $5$ different flights (iii) All Polish on same flight (iv) all Italians on same flight

Put all of $150$ Polish on one full flight in $5$ ways
Put the $100$ Italians on another flight in $4$ ways
$4$ flights have $500$ free seats but only $250$ passengers to seat, so add $250$ ghosts
Distribute the ghosts in $\binom{253}{3}$ ways
$v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ seats, $\Sigma{v_i}=250$ will be available for each distribution of the ghosts, so seat the $250$ pasengers in $\dbinom{250}{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}$ ways
Final answer = $5\cdot4\cdot\dbinom{253}3\dbinom{250}{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4}$

For a much simpler solution (since it doesn't mention that the French can't be in a separate plane) we might as well put them in a separate plane, and then distribute the Americans in two planes.
$5\cdot4\cdot3\cdot\binom{200}{150}$

Of course, it all seems a bit ridiculous. If we invoke the spirit of bonhomie that the Olympics are supposed to generate, we could just distribute all the athletes in four planes in $\dbinom{500}{150}\dbinom{350}{150}\dbinom{200}{150}$ ways

Dispose of all Polish... is clearly not intended to be genocidal.

@Daniel Mathias: Perish the thought,  have amended !
